# Specifying a strftime format to speed up pandas' to_datetime() method

Tags: python, pandas, strftime

Consider the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
some_time='01/01/2011 12:02:41 AM'
print(pd.to_datetime(some_time))
print(pd.to_datetime(some_time, format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %r'))
```

The first `to_datetime()` conversion works and prints the output

```
2011-01-01 00:02:41
```

Unfortunately, in my real application I'm dealing with a DataFrame with over 2 million rows and the default `to_datetime()` is prohibitively slow, even if I set `infer_datetime_format=True` in the keyword arguments.

I've read that `to_datetime()` can be sped up by specifying the string format explicitly. I've tried this following http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm, but my attempt above fails with the error `ValueError: 'r' is a bad directive in format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %r'`.

How can I specify the correct strftime format to convert `'01/01/2011 12:02:41 AM'` to datetime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need `%p` instead of `%r`. The difference is `%r` expects punctuation (A.M. or P.M.), whereas `%p` does not (AM or PM).

Your code does not produce any errors when I make the change:

```
pd.to_datetime(some_time, format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was given by [root](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3339965/root) in a comment. For the sake of completeness, the `%r` needs to be replaced by a `%p`:

```
some_time='01/01/2011 12:02:41 AM'
print(pd.to_datetime(some_time))
print(pd.to_datetime(some_time, format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
```

This yields the output

```
2011-01-01 00:02:41
2011-01-01 00:02:41
```

that is, the same output with and without the `format` keyword argument.